# Unique combinations of datapoints into two bins?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinations

I have a set of data of size $X$, say  $X = 7$. I want to find all of the unique ways that the data can be grouped into two bins of a minimum size of two. For the example where $X = 7$, I have:

```
 Bin A: 5     4
 Bin B: 2     3
```

As the possible arrangements. What I need is what the actual arrangements are. So if the data for $X = 7$ up there is $A B C D E F G$ for the first column there then I need:

Combination 1:
     Bin A: A B C D E
     Bin B: F G

Combination 2:
     Bin A: A B C D G
     Bin B: F E

Combination 3:
     Bin A: A B E D G
     Bin B: F C

etc.

until I have all possible combinations for the data. The restictions I have are that a bin has to have a minimum size of 2 and the bins are non-unique, so {A B} is the same as {B A}.

Comment: What is the *actual values* you want?

Comment: Although you labeled the bins A and B, it seems in summarizing the possible arrangements you consider them interchangeable.  Is it so?  Also "data points" would ordinarily be distinguishable, but you seem to consider only the number of data points in a bin as constituting an "arrangement".  We Readers just want to understand what you are trying to count.  Even when $X=60$ it is not hard to tell how many such "arrangements" are possible between two bins.

Comment: Sorry, let me try and clear it up here and then I'll try and edit my post so it's more useful for others. 

I have a pool of data, each individual datapoint can be grouped according to a common feature within the dataset. So say I have twenty total datapoints which can be divided into four groups, one of 10, one of 5, one of 4, and one that is a single outlier.

The single outlier is discarded, I need every possible combination of the groups 10, 5, and 4. Not "How many combinations are there" but "What, specifically, are the combinations?" The bins don't matter since (6 4) counts as (4 6).

Comment: Hopefully that question is much more readable, since I edited it up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we need is to split set $A$ with $X$ elements into two subsets $C$ and $D$ with at least two elements each.

To split this into two sets of size $x$ and $X-x$ we can select randomly $x$ elements. We can do that in $\binom{X}{x}$ ways. Notice, that selecting $X-x$ elements out of $X$ would give the same result. Thus we need to do groupings for $x\leq \left\lfloor\frac{X}{2}\right\rfloor$

Finally the number of splitting elements into two bins with alt least two elements each is equal to

$$\sum_{x=2}^{\left\lfloor\frac{X}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{X}{x}$$

For example for $X=7$ we have
$$\sum_{x=2}^{3}\binom{7}{x} = \binom{7}{2}+\binom{7}{3}=21+35=56 $$

The algorithm could be represented simply by following python code:

```
import math

X=7
possibleLengths=range(2, int(math.floor(X/2))+1)

def GetAllPossibleSubsets(prefix, minimumValue, numberOfElements):
  if numberOfElements == 0:
    print prefix
    return
  if X-minimumValue < numberOfElements:
    return 
  for x in range(minimumValue, X):
    GetAllPossibleSubsets(prefix+[x], x+1, numberOfElements-1)

for x in possibleLengths:
  GetAllPossibleSubsets([], 0, x)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm not after the number of combinations though, I'm after the combinations themselves. In your example, you have an output of 56, but what I need is what the 56 combinations actually are.

Comment: @gettothenextscreen: I think you could update your question because everyone would like to help you *barely* understand what you actually want from your question. Why not edit your question so you don't have to explain to everyone in the comment?

Comment: I should! I did try to explain I was after the actual values and not the number of possibilities, but you’re absolutely right that I should clarify that.

Comment: @gettothenextscreen the brute-force procedure of getting all of the combinations is already described using python script (actually it's the procedure of filling the first bin - you could easilly write a function, that puts the remaining elements into the second bin). There is no other way of gaining all of them than the brute-force method.

Comment: Ah, I actually had misread your python code. Thank you! That's exactly what I'm after, actually. If I'm reading it correctly it gives me half of the equation which means I can simply subtract those values from a parent array containing all possible values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assume those $n$ objects are all distinct, then the function you need to generate all combinations of $C(n,r)$ is called **nextCombination**$^{\dagger}$.

First, label each of your $n$ objects with a number in $\{1,2,3\dots,n\}$ so there is a one-to-one correspondence between the numbers and your objects. With some rules, you can generate all distinct $C(n,r)$ combinations:

(1) Since you want to pick $r$ out of $n$ objects, the starting sequence is $123\textrm{...r}$, and you also need the sequence $123\textrm{...n}$.

(2) Compare their last digit: the last digit of your $123\textrm{...r}$ and the last digit of a the sequence $123\textrm{...n}$.

(3) If they are the same, go on to compare their one-before-the-last digit and so on. If they're not, increase this digit in your $123\textrm{...r}$ by one, truncate those following digits, and append the same number of digits truncated to the digit you just increased, each of such digit is one more than the digit at its left hand side. (See the example because it's hard for me to describe it well.)

As you can verify, the sequence $143$ won't appear the list. So you won't re-count the combination represented by $134$.

---

### Example:

Consider the case $C(5,3)$:

$
n:12345\\
r:123$

That $5\not=3$, so the next one is $12(3+1)=124$.

When $r$ is $145$, then $5=5,4=4,3\not=1$, so $145\to 1\_\ \_\to 2\_\ \_\to 2\ 3\ \_\to 2\ 3\ 4\to 234$.

And actually you can start from any sequence $a_1a_2a_3$ s.t. $a_1<a_2<a_3$. So $245\to345$, and this is the end of $C(5,3)$!

---

$^{\dagger}$if you want to dive into the details of code, see [my little program in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/190982/126584), the function has only fifteen lines. But in general don't care which language I used, the logic is the same, it's called **algorithm**.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking through your code and while I don't understand C++ very well I do want to thank you for writing a reference, which helps. If I understand it correctly, you have a code that chooses *r* objects from the pool *n*. My issue is that I need two bins which sum to *n*, so I **think** the adaptation of your code I need is to generate all bins *r* and then a corresponding bin of the remaining members of *n* and dump all bins whose size is <2 and which has a bin of equal values on the other side. I'm trying to think of a way to do this that isn't computationally doubling the work.

Comment: @gettothenextscreen: E.g. you want $n=7$, each bin$\ge2$, so you have to compute (5,2), (4,3), (3,4), (2,5). But since this is a symmetry you just have to compute (5,2), (4,3). So I don't know why you think its a doubling work? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: And when you computing, e.g. say (5,2): you just have to use the code by finding all $C(7,2)=21$, say the result is $r(1,3)$ then since you don't care the order in each bin, you just have to do $\{1,2,\dots,7\}\backslash \{1,3\}$ to find another bin, and this is also easy to achieve use simple data structure I think almost all languages already support. If you think this is still a double please edit your question so everyone can help you, because you question **isn't** very clear.

Comment: If it counts {5 3} as distinct from {3 5} then it is doing double the computational work it needs to.

Comment: @gettothenextscreen: Why? you just have to reverse the "tags" for the bins of {5,3} then you will get the result for {3,5}

Comment: (6,2), (5,3), (4,4) loop **stop**. now if you want to know about (3,5), (2,6), simply *reverse the tags* of (5,3), (2,6)! You can design your for-loop to stop at the point (a,b) s.t. $a\ge b$.

Comment: For me nothing is doubling: You only have to store the results (6,2), (5,3), (4,4) when you want (3,5), **sort it** into (a,b) s.t. $a\ge b$, i.e. (5,3). then **search it** in your database, so you will find (5, 3). Now **reverse the tags**. End procedure.

Comment: Sorry, as I mentioned I’m not at all familiar with C++